# Finitely Generated Abelian Groups and Subgroups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

I am working on the following problem to prepare for an exam.

In the following cases, find a basis {$α_1$, ..., $α_n$} for $G$ such that the
subgroup $H$ has a basis of the form {$m_1·α_1$, ..., $m_k ·α_k$} for some integers $m_1, ..., m_k$.

(1) $G = Z^2$
, H is all $(a, b)$ such that $a + b$ is even.

(2) $G = Z^3$
, $H$ is all $(a, b, c)$ such that 7 divides $a + b + c$.

(3) $G = Z^4$
, $H$ is all $(a, b, c, d)$ such that $a + b = 0$ and $c + d = 0$.

Here is what I have thought about so far.

For $1$, I know that if $a + b$ is even then the elements must have the form $(2k, 2j)$ or $(2k + 1, 2j + 1)$. I believe a basis for $H$ would then be $(2,0),(1,1)$. However, I know that a basis for $Z^2$ must have length $2$ so I believe that $(1,1), (0,1)$ satisfies this since this definitely "spans" $Z^2$.

For $2$ I have thought that since $7 | a + b +c$ then $H$ must be generated by $(7,0,0), (0,7,0), (5,1,1)$ (I'm not entirely sure if this is correct, though) and so the basis for $Z^3$ would be $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(5,1,1)$ which is indeed a basis.

Lastly, for $3$ I have thought that if $a + b = 0$ then we must have one of the spanning vectors be $(1,-1,0,0)$ and the other spanning vector would be of the form $(0,0,1,-1)$. For any element $h \in H$, $h = (a,-a,c,-c) = a(1,-1,0,0) + b(0,0,1,-1)$ so this is indeed a basis for $H$. So extending this to a basis for $G$, yields for example $(1,-1,0,0), (0,0,1,-1), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0)$.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could correct, and perhaps let me know if there is a simpler way to do this kind of problem.

Comment: Your proposed basis for $G$ in 1 doesn’t work, because the basis you propose for $H$ does not have the required form. However, you can take $\alpha_1=(1,0)$ and $\alpha_2=(1,1)$ as the basis for $G$; in which case the basis for $H$ has the form $2\alpha_1,1\alpha_2$.

Comment: Your basis for $H$ in 2 doesn’t work: you cannot express $(0,6,1)$ as a linear combination of them: the coefficient of $(5,1,1)$ would necessarily be $1$, and then there is no way to cancel out the $5$ in the first coordinate.

Comment: Note that you aren’t just trying to extend the basis for $H$ to a basis for $G$. You are trying to find a basis for $G$ with the property that multiples of the first $k$ elements of the basis for $G$ yields a basis for $H$. So I don’t think you are approaching the problem correctly.

Comment: Ah, for $1$ I believe I meant $(0,2), (1,1)$, thank you for pointing that out. For $2$, I see what you are saying. Is there an obvious way to get all elements $(a,b,c)$ such that $7 | a + b +c$? I can see that you, in principle would have to fix $c$ after choosing $a$ and $b$ in order to be able to get everything in $H$.

Comment: I suppose what I'm unsure about is - is there an algorithm for finding such a basis or is it trial-and-error?

Comment: Smith Normal form comes to mind...